Persistent volume claim status pending?
My pvc is not bound to the volume after creation.
My Persistent Volume file is:
# mysql-pv.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  namespace: ns-flask-app
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi # Adjust the size as needed
  volumeMode: Block
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # This should match your PVC access mode
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-ddb08872db52adb64
    fsType: ext4
  storageClassName: standard # Replace with your storage class name if applicable
# hostPath:
# path: /mysql/data # Replace with the host path for your storage

My Persistent  Volume Claim file is:
# mysql-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
  namespace: ns-flask-app
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # Should match the PV access mode
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi # Request the same size as the PV
  storageClassName: standard # Replace with your storage class name if applicable


And my Statefulset file is:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-statefulset
  namespace: ns-flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pythonapp-db
  serviceName: mysql-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pythonapp-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql-container
          image: mysql:5.7
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: username
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            - name: mysql-config
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-config
          configMap:
            name: mysql-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mysql-pvc
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2Gi
                                                        

Upon creating the resources, I get the following:



I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. My volume is Amazon EBS.
I have changed a few parameters in all the files, deleted the resources, and re-created them all over again...all to no avail. I am not sure why the pvc is not bound to the volume.
